# Fit birth-death ODE model incorporating uncertainty in measured data

Tags: python, fitting, scipy, differential-equations

I have the birth-death model $dy/dt = br \cdot x(t) - dr \cdot y(t)$ where the change of $y$ depends on the birth-rate $br$ and $x$ at timepoint $t$ and death rate $dr$ and $y$ at time point $t$.

$x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are functions that model measured data including a confidence interval / standard deviation at time point $t$.

I can use `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` and `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to infer parameters $br$ & $dr$ for the best fit of $y$ data. Meaning that the sum of the squared residuals of `model_to_fit(t, br, dr) - y` is minimized.

```
def model_to_fit(t, br, dr):
   solution = solve_ivp(ODE, ...)
   return solution.y

(br, dr), pcov = curve_fit(model_to_fit, t, y, ...)
```

I can also incorporate the uncertainty of $y$ by using the `sigma` parameter of `curve_fit`. Then the optimized function is `chisq = sum((r / sigma) ** 2)`
However, how can I incorporate the uncertainty of $x$? So that the variance of the parameter estimation includes uncertainties of both $x$ & $y$. And can I compute a goodness of fit metric that incorporates the uncertainty of $x$? Maybe a log-likelihood that I can use for BIC calculation?